# OpenTSDB - Get all metrics via http

Tags: c#, opentsdb

I am getting some data from OpenTSDB, but cannot work out how to get a list of metrics via http?

For reference, here's the c# code I'm using to get databack. Is there a url that would return all metrics?

```
var request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:4242/api/version?jsonp=callback");
request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
string text;
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    text = sr.ReadToEnd();
}

uxResponse.Text = text;
```

The default OpenTSDB website provides this functionality as per following screenshot, I want to mimic this from a my asp site.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, api/suggest returns the list based on matching supplied parameter. This will get me out of trouble on this question, although it doesn't return all metrics it gives me a method to make it work.

**Example Request Query String**

```
http://localhost:4242/api/suggest?type=metrics&q=sys&max=10
```

**JSON Content**

```
{
  "type":"metrics",
  "q":"sys",
  "max":10
}
```

I hope this helps anyone else, basically RTFM! (http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/api_http/suggest.html)

Comment: You can leave "q" empty to get a list of all metrics i.e.

"q":"" 

or

use suggest?type=metrics&q= in the query