# How to find all metrics associated to a tag value

Tags: opentsdb

Given a particular tag value, is there a way to obtain the list of all metrics associated to it?

**Example**

- tags (key=value)

  - host=box1.onenet.tv
  - host=box2.onenet.tv
- metrics

  - net.bytes_received
  - net.bytes_sent
  - net.error_count
- metrics associated to tag value "box1.onenet.tv"

  - net.bytes_received
  - net.bytes_sent
  - net.error_count"

How to obtain "net.bytes_received,net.bytes_sent,net.error_count" using tag value "box1.onenet.tv"?

Answer (score 1):

No, i don't think that you can find data without a given metric but only by giving a tag name. The metric name is the biggest aggregation level. Below one metric you can only use  tags to find special areas of data.
Perhaps you have to shift your metric name down into the tagnames, so that you define a new common metric name which fits on all your possible aggregation queries. Then you can search for all tags with your old metric name in the metric with your new common metric name. Hope that was understandable.

By the way and more detailed for your information:
In your query you can use wildcards for your tags (e.g.  tag1=*), but not for the metric name.

Here is an overview about what your query consist of (see: http://opentsdb.net/query-execution.html):

```
All queries have:
  - A metric name for which to retrieve data;
  - A start time;
  - A stop time (optional, if not set, assumed to be "now");
  - A possibly empty set of tags to filter the data
      (e.g. host=foo, or wildcards such as host=*);
  - An aggregation function (e.g. sum or avg);
    Whether or not to get the "rate of change" the data (in mathematical terms: 
    the first derivative). Optionally: a downsampling interval (e.g. 10 minutes) 
    and downsampling function (e.g. avg)
```

And i think it is very useful to read the OpenTSDB documentation, especially about metric and tags. See here: http://opentsdb.net/metrics.html

```
Right now, you cannot combine two metrics into one plot line.
This means you want a metric to be the biggest possible aggregation point. 
If you want to drill down to specifics within a metric, use tags.
```

Comment: I'm not so sure about your answer. I'm not trying to get data points but rather a list of metrics associated to a tag. It wouldn't be required to be through the query (are there any other way?).

Comment: Ok, i see. But i think, its not so simple. I found a post, how you can find all metrics by a search string, but there is no way to filter by tag. Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18396365/opentsdb-get-all-metrics-via-http

Answer (score 1):

FYI, it is possible with OpenTSDB 2.1.0, which introduces metadata handling:  [Google Groups: Pulling (meta)data from OpenTSDB](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/opentsdb/eo_CYCclnI0)

Remember to enable metadata parsing and then you can pull all the data you ever dreamed of :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [label endpoint](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#querying-label-values) to retrieve this:

```
https://<prometheus-url>/api/v1/label/__name__/values?match[]={host=box1.onenet.tv}
```

This will show you all label `__name__` (i.e. the metric names) associated with that filter (`host=box1.onenet.tv`).

This will provide a json with a list under the `data` key with all metrics that match the filter.

In your case the response to that URL will be something like

```
{"status": "success", "data": ["net.bytes_received" ,"net.bytes_sent", "net.error_count"]}
```